# Right arc less-than bracket, what is the meaning of?

Tags: finite-element-method

While studying the textbook of finite element method, there's one symbol I don't understand.

[image]

[image]

It is not listed in [Pakin's Comprehensive Latex Symbol List.](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)

I found it via wikipedia, see the following figure:

[image]

So it seems to be called "right arc less than"?

My questions are:

1. What is the math meaning of it?
2. What is the corresponding latex code of it?
3. If possible, any relevant math textbooks about it?

Comment: It allmost certainly means "the angle between".

Comment: thanks. and the corresponding latex symbols for that, please?

Comment: It looks like an overstrike of < and ).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a common symbol for angles and what are semantic differences?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/640838/what-is-a-common-symbol-for-angles-and-what-are-semantic-differences)