# How are angles measured?

Tags: geometry

I have a question about the measure of angle. we know that $ 0^∘≤m∠XOY≤360^∘$ or $ 0≤m∠XOY≤2π $.

Is
$$m∠XOY\in \mathbb{N}$$  or is $$ m∠XOY \in \mathbb{R}$$ ?

Comment: I cannot make sense of your symbols.

Comment: @ahorn ,m∠xoy: measur of the angle ∠xoy

Comment: $m$ is useless then

Comment: @ahorn .Does the size of the angle is a real number or integer?

Comment: An angle could be any real number. But I am wondering what are you implying? What's the purpose of this question?

Comment: @elham.mj I think you are confused between radians and degrees.

Answer (score 1):

How an angle $\angle(XOY)$ in the plane is measured: Draw rays $OX$ and $OY$ and intersect them with a unit circle centered at $O$. The length of the shorter arc between the two  points of intersection is the *(unsigned) angle* defined by the given configuration. This angle can be any real number between $0$ and $\pi$ inclusive.

In daily life we measure angles in degrees instead, whereby $1^\circ:={\pi\over180}$. Fractions of degrees can be expressed in decimals, like $23.7114^\circ$, or using (angle) minutes $\ ':={1^\circ\over60}\ $ and (angle) seconds $'':={1^\circ\over60\cdot60}$. This leads to angle data of the form $61^\circ 34'22.61''$.

But note that, whatever units are used, an angle is a "continuous real variable".

For more sophisticated versions of the notion of angle, see this question at MSE:   [What is the exact and precise definition of an ANGLE?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/583066/what-is-the-exact-and-precise-definition-of-an-angle/583119#583119)

Answer (score 0):

Unless stated otherwise, an angle is a real number (which allows us to be precise). $m$ is not used to denote an angle - rather, just write $\angle XOY$ to denote the angle subtended by the lengths $XO$ and $OY$.

Comment: Does it exist $\sqrt{2}^∘$ ? and What is؟

Comment: Yes, an angle can be an irrational number.

Comment: ahorn:  $\angle  XOY$ is a label for an angle being referenced, i.e. it's a name given to an angle.  The OP uses $m(\angle XOY),$ which refers to the measure of the angled named $\angle XOY$.  In any case it *is* true that the *measure* of an angle is a real number, whatever the unit used.